# missing data in Crystal Reports Subreport

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, subreport

I've got a collection of subreports. The code is virtually identical for each (I like patterns). Here's a sample of the one that's failing:

```
    ' subject
    sql = "select * from vw_UORSuspect where offense_id = " + offenseID.ToString
    GetData(sql, dsUORSubject, "vw_uorSubject", 0)
    If Not dsUORSubject.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
        mySection = UORrpt.ReportDefinition.Sections("DetailSection6")
        mySubObj = mySection.ReportObjects("Subreport3")
        mySubRep = mySubObj.OpenSubreport(mySubObj.SubreportName)
        mySubRep.SetDataSource(dsUORSubject)
        'mySubSection = UORrpt.Subreports.Item(0).ReportDefinition.Sections(1)
    End If
```

It's pretty straight forward. I load my dataset object, test to see if there's data and then stuff it into the report subsection. The data does get loaded to the dataset, which is easy to view.

There are two records in the dataset, as there are for the previous subreport which displays as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the result of a typo in the name of the view, as you can see if you look at the names. It took someone looking over my shoulder to make me see it.